# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I'm using this code to post into fb group automatically but got this error message.

```
  File "fbposter.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "fbposter.py", line 81, in main
    post_button.click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

The code

```
post_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-testid='react-composer-post-button']")
        clickable = False
        while not clickable:
            cursor = post_button.find_element_by_tag_name('span').value_of_css_property("cursor")
            if cursor == "pointer":
                clickable = True
                break
        post_button.click()
        sleep(5)
```

HTML code on FB group post

```
<button class="_1mf7 _4jy0 _4jy3 _4jy1 _51sy selected _42ft" data-testid="react-composer-post-button" type="submit" value="1"><div alt="" class="_3-8_ _2ph- _6q3h"><span class="img _55ym _55yn _55yp" role="progressbar" aria-valuetext="Loading..." aria-busy="true" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></span></div><span class="">Post</span></button>
```

Reference: https://github.com/lalongooo/selenium-fb-group-poster

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS clause 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [**`Facebook Graph API`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Comment: As per my prior requests, there is no need to add badly-spelled begging to every post. Please refrain from adding "please advice" to everything you write. Readers know you are seeking assistance by virtue of your posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer.

```
        sleep(5)
        buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
        sleep(5)
        for button in buttons:
            if button.text == "Post":
                button.click()
```

Comment: Try to modify as `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Post']").click()`